# PHP Laravel file processing in queue

Tags: laravel-4, queue

I am working on a project, which allows many users to upload files (csv,xls,xslx,xml), the files should be validated, and if valid, the data is stored in the database.

The files have strict naming convention and it will be validated during upload. The file content could be very long, so it cannot be validated during a request, this task will be pushed to a queue.

I would like to give the users some UI, where they can see their uploaded files. It is a table with a Status column, which is changing like: Uploaded, Validating, Importing to DB, Success, or possible Error after each step.

My questions is how can I monitor the jobs and display their status ?

Comment: it's simple,just consider a status column in your database which shows current step for each file you want.

Comment: I haven't dealt with queues before, and I am having trouble getting the status of the job and any return error from the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

I create a table for this let's call it: **files** which has these columns:

`id  |   url  |  status  | error |created_at  |  updated_at`

*status*'s default value is zero: file uploaded and needs validating.when it's 1: it's validated and successfully updated.

*error*'s default value is zero: file has no errors. and each value for *error* represents it's correspond error(for instance 1 shows file size is too big).

But you can have no *error* column. A *status* could show all of these by itself.